# Is it a good practice to have setter in the get instance property of a singleton class

Tags: c#, properties, singleton, getter-setter

In a singleton class, at some point in time, I need to dispose of the instance and clean the class and its members. For sure I cant use `IDispossible` interface.
Is it a good practice to have a `setter` in the `GetInstance` property and assign with null when am done with the use of the particular instance? Or to expose a static function from the `singleton` class to clear the existing instance explicitly?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/singleton-anti-pattern In short, no, it would not be a good idea. I would advise against using the singleton semi-pattern if you need to "dispose" at some point before the app exits. Typically, I would rarely use singleton, and only in cases where I do not need to unit test, and where I need to keep a single "connector" type object and where I will not bother with unit tests. So, mostly for a small proof of concept, not in production code.

Comment: thank you for the clarity, generally, this article speaks singleton as an Anti-pattern. It's a very rare case that I opted to use this pattern, I should think about changing it in production code.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

If you need to release *unmanaged* resources - the scenario where we would use `IDisposable`, then implement `IDisposable` and don't make the class a singleton.

If you have no unmanaged resources and a singleton is what you need, make it a singleton and don't worry about a "setter" to set things to null. It's not necessary.

---

You're trying to accomplish two things: making a class disposable and making it a singleton, and you've seen that the two don't go well together. Instead of dismissing `IDisposable` and looking for a different way to release managed resources, I'd do the opposite. Implement `IDisposable` but don't make the class a singleton.

Why? Primarily because there are usually other ways to enforce that only one instance of a class exists without making it a singleton. For example, most dependency injection containers, including `IServiceProvider`, make it easy to register a dependency as a singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<ThingThatIOnlyWantOneOf>();
```

That doesn't mean that `ThingThatIOnlyWantOneOf` actually is a singleton. We could create multiple instances of it. We're just indicating that we only want to create one instance, and use it over and over.

Even if we don't use any IoC/DI container we can still limit the number of instances of a class we create without actually making it a singleton. (And that gives us the flexibility to change our mind if/when we realize that we do need more instances.)

Now the problem of how to write the class as a singleton *and* make the class disposable has disappeared. We're using a different means to create and re-use one instance of the class, and that class can be disposable.

---

It's also worth noting that setting something to null is not the same thing as implementing `IDisposable`.

We generally don't go around setting object references to null when we're done with them because the .NET Framework handles that for us. An object goes out of scope when there are no more references to it, and then the garbage collector removes it from memory. All of that happens efficiently without us doing anything. That's why you don't see extra lines of code at the end of methods to set objects to null.

We only implement `IDisposable` when a class deals with unmanaged resources - for example, SQL connections or open file streams. Those classes have to actually do something to release their resources, and we want it to happen as soon as possible.

What that means is that if something *did* need to be disposable, then just setting it to null wouldn't accomplish that. We would want to actually call `Dispose()`. If it doesn't actually need to be disposable then we don't need to set it to null anyway. We can just let it go out of scope and get garbage collected.

So if you're concerned that you need to "clear" something or set something to null, you probably don't. `IDisposable` exists to mark things that need to be "cleaned up." It's a way of knowing that if something *doesn't* implement that then we don't need to worry about it. (Otherwise we'd go around setting everything to null just out of doubt and uncertainty, and that wouldn't be as much fun.)

Comment: Appreciate your answer, it explains clearly, but in my use case Singleton really fit at its best, and I can't get rid of it. I never used IDisposible, I mentioned that I don't want that implementation. So still my concern to clearing the active instance before exiting the application is valid. 
Maybe a private-setter or a function can allow me to do it. Can you validate this statemet please?

Comment: I updated the answer. If something doesn't need to be disposable then you might not have anything to be concerned about. You probably don't need to clear anything. If you're not sure then you could describe what it is you think you might need to clear or set to null. But you probably don't need to do that.

Comment: thanks, @scot, I'm mostly avoiding singleton pattern, because of the setting the value to the instance explicitly isn't a nice idea. as you said I need to set the instance as null which is bad as I see now. thanks for the idea

Comment: also, this portion of the code doesn't deal with any unmanaged code, so that i don't care about the `IDispossible` interface

Comment: No, I hope I didn't explain badly. You probably *don't* need to set the instance to null. If there are no unmanaged resources then you don't have to do anything.

Comment: yes technically that's correct, also i cant assign new instance from outside so the statement stands with validity